# swiftで１つのcollectionViewに２つのcollectionViewCellを表示させる方法

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

プログラム初心者です。

１つのコレクションビューに２つのコレクションビューセルを表示させるため、プログラムを書いたのですが、２つ目のセルが表示されません。

どなたか解決法をご教示いただけないでしょうか。

２種類のカスタムセルはサブクラス化し、別々のファイルで作成しました。

以下、ViewController.swiftのコードです。

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupSubviews()
        self.autolayoutSubviews()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func setupSubviews() {
        let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(300.0, 100.0)

        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        self.collectionView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.collectionView!.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView!.delegate = self
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(Cell1.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell1")
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(Cell2.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell2")
        self.collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView!)
    }

    func autolayoutSubviews() {
        self.collectionView!.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor).active = true
        self.collectionView!.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor).active = true
        self.collectionView!.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor).active = true
        self.collectionView!.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor).active = true
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell1: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell1
        cell1.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        return cell1

        let cell2: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell2
        //cell2.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        //return cell2
    }
}
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 2種類のCellをどのように表示し分けるおつもりでしょう。実用的なアプリであれば、最初がCell1次がCell2のように固定していることはないかと思います。どのようなセルを表示する必要があるかどうか、システムからあなたのアプリに伝えられる情報はindexPathだけです。まずは、indexPathからどのようにセルを使い分けるのか考えてください。後は自然に`collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)`メソッドでそれをどう実現すれば良いかが見えてくるはずです。別件ですが、「回答」により問題が解決した場合には、その「回答」を承認するのをお忘れなく。

Comment: [回答の承認](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)はあくまでオプションであり義務ではないのですが、まだ回答を受け付けているのか、それとも問題は解決したのかということが分かりやすくなります。

Comment: 2種類のcellでそれぞれのcell内のレイアウトを変えたい、と言うのはわかるのですが、どこにどちらのセルを表示すれば良いのかお聞きしているのですが?

Comment: まだ十分にうまく定義できていないように思うのですが、「同じ数」にさえなれば、Cell1とCell2はランダムに配置されても良いということでしょうか？そうではなく、規則性があるのであれば、きちんとその規則を説明できませんか？少しうるさいように思うかもしれませんが、自分のやりたいことを他人にもうまく伝わるように説明できれば、プログラミングの問題の大半は解決できます。少々お手間かもしれませんが、Cell1とCell2をどんな規則で並べたいのか、説明してみていただけませんか。

Comment: まだ私の意図が伝わっていないようです(私自身もどう伝えるのか、学習しないといけないようですね)が、例えば最初の一つのセルをCell1にするかCell2にするかはどう決まるのですか？

Comment: セルに表示される中身によって動的に変える、順番で交互に変える、それ以外の謎の何かで変える、複数のセルを使い分ける場合は色々ありますが、それぞれにやり方は変わってきます。セル1とセル2を交互に並べれば良いと言うことで、私なりの回答を書いてみますので、お試しください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントで確認させてもらったように、今回はセル1とセル2を交互に、と言うことにしておきます。
(コメントのやり取りの中で、あいまいだった条件がはっきりしてきた場合、できればご質問を編集して追記しておいてください。)

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //indexPathから、どちらのcellを表示するかの情報を取得する
    //今回は偶数番目ならCell1, 奇数番目ならCell2とする
    let cellTypeNumber = indexPath.item % 2

    switch cellTypeNumber {
    case 0:
        //セルID="Cell1"に結びつけたクラスがCell1であること
        let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell1
        cell1.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        return cell1
    //`case 1`としたいところだが、`caseを尽くしていない`というエラーを避けるため`default`にする
    default:
        //セルID="Cell2"に結びつけたクラスがCell2であること
        let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell2
        cell2.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        return cell2
    }
}
```

もしかしたら、「それで良いんなら近いことをやってみたんだが…」と言ったコードになっているかもしれません。お試しの上、うまくいかない点があればおしらせください。